# Show hidden select field on change using script in cakephp

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp

I wrote this script to show hidden label and whole select field on change in other select field CakePHP,
script function is showing label but not select field.

Here is the htmlhelper:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="job_category" class="col-sm-5 control-label">Tutor City</label>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('city_id',
            array('class' => 'user_login form-control',
                  'placeholder' =>'TutorCity',
                  'label' => false,
                  'div' => false,
                  'id' => 'city'
            ));
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="job_category" class="col-sm-5 control-label" id="area_label" hidden>Tutor Access Areas</label>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('area_id',
            array('class' => 'user_login form-control',
                  'placeholder' => 'TutorAreas',
                  'id' => 'area',
                  'div' => false,
                  'label' => false,
                  'multiple' => true,
                  'type' => 'hidden'
            ));
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#city").change(function () {
        $("#area_label").show();
        $("#area").show();
    })
</script>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is your code creating multiple elements with the ID of "area"?  If so, then it won't work because IDs must be unique.  Use a class instead of an ID.

Comment: As far as why `$("#area").show()` isn't working, it would be more helpful to see the final HTML that that is rendered.

Comment: @Tony it gives an error if i use class 
error is .. array to string conversion.

Comment: I don't really know Cake or PHP, so I can't help you with the server side.  Another way to approach this would be to wrap the elements you want to hide in one static div with an ID, and then `.show()` that div.

Comment: Thank you mate..worked very fine.
i dont know why i was't considering warping the field.

Answer (score 0):

The second input is hidden input `<input type="hidden">` so to generate select field remove `type => hidden`

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('area_id',
            array('class' => 'user_login form-control',
                  'placeholder' => 'TutorAreas',
                  'id' => 'area',
                  'div' => false,
                  'label' => false,
                  'multiple' => true,
                  'type' => 'hidden' // remove this
            ));
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the type hidden first. You can try using type text with display none. You can change the input field display block on change.